# Issue with Teradata SQL query

Tags: sql, teradata

I am having some trouble with the following SQL Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ACC_NO
FROM FIRST_TABLE A
WHERE A.ACC_NO = 1
AND A.ACC_NO NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ACC_NO
    FROM SECOND_TABLE B                            
    LEFT JOIN THIRD_TABLE C
    ON B.FIELD_NAME = C.FIELD_NAME
)
ORDER BY A.ACC_NO
```

The follwing query doesn't return anything, even though I know for a fact that the inner select doesn't contain an entry with an ACC_NO of 1. If I run the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACC_NO
FROM SECOND_TABLE B                            
LEFT JOIN THIRD_TABLE C
ON B.FIELD_NAME = C.FIELD_NAME
WHERE ACC_NO = 1
```

it doesn't return anything.

However, the query **does** work if I include "WHERE ACC_NO <> 1" in the inner select (of the first query).

How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` returns *no rows* if *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`.

For this reason, I strongly recommend that you always use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`.  So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ACC_NO
FROM FIRST_TABLE A
WHERE A.ACC_NO = 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM SECOND_TABLE B LEFT JOIN                           
                       THIRD_TABLE C
                       ON B.FIELD_NAME = C.FIELD_NAME
                  WHERE ?.ACC_NO = A.ACC_NO
                 );
```

The `?.ACC_NO` is because I don't know which table has `ACC_NO`, although I could speculate that it is `B`.

Comment: I get an error when I try to add in "NOT EXISTS". Does it not work in Teradat SQL?

Comment: @klippy . . . `NOT EXISTS` definitely works in Teradata.  There was a typo in the answer.

Comment: I've copied and pasted your exact code but it's still showing up as an error. Could my version of teradata not support it?

Comment: @klippy . . . You need to replace `?` with the alias of the table that the column comes from.

Comment: The "A.ACC_NO AND NOT EXISTS" part seems to be the problem. If I remove "A.ACC_NO AND" it runs. It doesn't get me the right answer, but there isn't an error

Comment: I think I have it now

    SELECT DISTINCT A.ACC_NO
    FROM FIRST_TABLE A
    AND NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ACC_NO
        FROM SECOND_TABLE B                            
        LEFT JOIN THIRD_TABLE C
        ON B.FIELD_NAME = C.FIELD_NAME
        WHERE WH_ACC_NO = A.WH_ACC_NO
    )
    ORDER BY A.ACC_NO

Answer (score 0):

The NOT IN is rewritten to a join (check the explain). Joining with Null -values is "undefined", meaning: "no fun". 
Try to add "WHERE ACC_NO IS NOT NULL" to the inner SQL.